# Should we delete the tag "hot"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently saw the tag "hot" in a question. However, looking at the questions tagged with this, both temperature-related and spiciness-related meanings are used.

Either meanings have better tags, e.g. temperature or spicy-hot (or others, I haven't checked carefully).

Could we please delete this tag?

Comment: This meta question actually asks for this, and many others. I have no idea if this was implemented or not (question is 6 years old). http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/467/tags-that-should-probably-be-deleted

Comment: I noticed it too. Temp and spicy-hot are better tags even without the ambiguity.

Answer (score 6):

I agree. I already tag-edited all questions where it was used to mean [temperature](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temperature), [hot-sauce](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hot-sauce) and, in two cases, [hot-chocolate](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hot-chocolate).

For the spicy-hot use, I created a tag synonym suggestion. Please vote on it: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/spicy-hot/synonyms.

Comment: I went ahead and just merged hot into spicy-hot (which creates the synonym directly).

Answer (score 1):

How about two tags:

- hot (temperature)
- hot (spicy)

I don't know if tags support parenthesis.

Comment: There's already [tag:spicy-hot] and [tag:temperature]. And, no, you can't use punctuation other than dashes (as word separators). As a note, there is no longer a tag [tag:hot]. It's already been deleted. :)